# structural search Intellij IDEA : Howto find occurrences of all classes extending another class

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

is there a way to search for all occurences of subclasses of a particular class ?

Say I have a class `AbstractItem` and I have got a lot of implementations of this `AbstractItem` class. Now I want to know where all subclasses are used.

Can I search for all occurences of all subclasses with a structural search pattern in Intellij IDEA ?

Thanks,
Detlef

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is use the following:

Search template:
`$A$`

Set *Expression type (regexp)* to `AbstractItem` and check the *Apply constraint within type hierarchy* checkbox (under *Edit Variables...*).

This will find all expressions with type or subtype of `AbstractItem`.